# Oracle can trigger be a parent object of another db object?

Tags: oracle, triggers, parent-child

I am trying to find a scenario where trigger would be a `REFERENCED_TYPE` in `DBA_DEPDENDENCIES` table, which means there are objects in the DB which are depending on the `TRIGGER`. Can there be such a scenario ?

Whenever I create a trigger calling a function or a function calling a DML which would fire trigger I see that TRIGGER is a child object (TYPE) but not parent object (REFERENCED_TYPE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger needs to be referenced(implicitly, you cannot reference(call) a trigger explicitly) to appear in the `referenced_type` column of the `dba_dependencies`data dictionary view.

`Can there be such a scenario ?`

Here is one I can think of right now (you need to be on Oracle 11g or higher). You create a couple of triggers of the same type(same timing point) and specify order of firing: `follows <<trigger_name>>` or `precedes <<trigger_name>>`.

```
--drop table foo purge;

create table foo(c1 number);

create or replace trigger tr_foobi_1
before insert on foo
for each row
begin
  null;
end;
/

create or replace trigger tr_foobi_2
before insert on foo
for each row
follows tr_foobi_1
begin
  null;
end;
/

column name format a10;
column type format a10;
column referenced_name format a17;
column referenced_type format a17;

select name
     , type
     , referenced_name
     , referenced_type
  from dba_dependencies
 where referenced_type = 'TRIGGER';

Result:

NAME       TYPE       REFERENCED_NAME   REFERENCED_TYPE  
---------- ---------- ----------------- -----------------
TR_FOOBI_2 TRIGGER    TR_FOOBI_1        TRIGGER
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps.